# Chat Javascript não retorna função

Tags: javascript, html5, chat, firebase

Soube que o *Firebase* é uma API que ajuda a criar *apps em tempo real*, porém seguindo um pouco que conheço sobre JS, tentei criar um chat. Não entendi exatamente o por que não consegui retornar mensagem.

abaixo deixo o código de estudo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.17/firebase.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
<body>

  <div id="mensagens"></div>

  <input type="text" id="nomeusuario" placeholder="digitar nome">
  <input type="text" id="mensagem" placeholder="digitar mensagem">

    <script>
    var APP new Firebase("https://nomedomeuapp.firebaseio.com/");

        $("#mensagem").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.Keycode == 13) {
                var = msg $("#mensagem").val()
                var = usr $("#nomeusuario").val()
                APP.push({ nomeusuario: usr, mensagem: msg });

                $("#mensagem").val('');

            }
        });

        APP.on('child_added', Function(mostra) {
              var novamensagem = mostra.val()//para receber a mensagem
              carregaMensagem(novamensagem.nomeusuario, novamensagem.mensagem);
        });

        function carregamensagem(nome, mensagem) {
            $('<div/>').text(mensagem)
            .prepend($('<strong/>').text(nome + ': '))
            .apprendTo($('#mensagens'));

            $('#mensagens')[0].scrollTop = $('#mensagens')[0].scrollHeight;
        };
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Vi alguns erros:

Troque isso

```
var APP new Firebase("https://nomedomeuapp.firebaseio.com/");
```

por isso

```
var APP = new Firebase("https://nomedomeuapp.firebaseio.com/");
```

Troque isso

```
var = msg $("#mensagem").val()
var = usr $("#nomeusuario").val()
```

por isso

```
var msg =  $("#mensagem").val();
var usr = $("#nomeusuario").val();
```

troque isso

```
APP.on('child_added', Function(mostra) ...
```

por isso

```
APP.on('child_added', function(mostra) ...
```

O resto está correto ao meu ver.

Answer (score 2):

Além do que foi falado acima pelo Edgar, na linha onde tem isso:

```
 APP.on('child_added', Function(mostra)
```

troque por isso, a palavra "function" deve ser minúscula

```
APP.on('child_added', function(mostra)
```